# How to Use API 's in classic ASP use of VB script

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Now i have to do some modifications in our old website which is developed in classic asp and vb script.but am not familiar with vb script.now i want to know how to use API's  in classic with vb script and how read that xml output by using of vb script?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Have a look at this though http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_server.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unfortunately a bit too vague to form a useful response. However, you should know that it is certainly possible to do.

Without any knowledge of the type of API you are discussing, let's just say in general terms that it is likely you will be utilizing the XMLHTTP object to create your 'request' to the API (though much here depends on the specifics of your API, whether it is SOAP, etc.), so you can start looking around for more information on that.

Retrieving and using the response will depend (again) on the specifics of your API. It is likely that you will be utilizing standard XML objects to iterate and retrieve the data you wish to work with.

For some interesting examples to help get you started, check out these:

http://benenewton.com/2009/09/02/calling-the-usps-api-via-classic-asp/
http://www.twilio.com/blog/2010/04/using-twilio-with-classic-asp-and-vbscript.html
http://classicaspreference.com/aspexamples/save_remote_images_with_photobucket_rss_xml.asp